# Why is there no overload of Interlocked.Add that accepts Doubles as parameters?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, atomic, interlocked

I fully appreciate the atomicity that the Threading.Interlocked class provides; I don't understand, though, why the Add function only offers two overloads: one for Integers, another for Longs. Why not Doubles, or any other numeric type for that matter?

Clearly, the intended method for changing a Double is CompareExchange; I am GUESSING this is because modifying a Double is a more complex operation than modifying an Integer. Still it isn't clear to me why, if CompareExchange and Add can both accept Integers, they can't also both accept Doubles.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The Interlocked class wraps around the Windows API Interlocked** functions.

These are, in turn, wrapping around the native processor API, using the LOCK instruction prefix for x86.  It only supports prefixing the following instructions:

> BT, BTS, BTR, BTC, XCHG, XADD, ADD, OR, ADC, SBB, AND, SUB, XOR, NOT, NEG, INC, DEC

You'll note that these, in turn, pretty much map to the interlocked methods.  Unfortunately, the ADD functions for non-integer types are not supported here.  Add for 64bit longs is supported on 64bit platforms.

Here's a great article [discussing lock semantics on the instruction level](http://www.codemaestro.com/reviews/8).

Comment: The link is not active anymore. Here's a backup from Internet Archive https://web.archive.org/web/20160319061137/http://www.codemaestro.com/reviews/8

Comment: You forgot `lock cmpxchg` and `lock cmpxchg8b`.  Maybe you're looking at the manual from an ancient 386, before that flexible building-block was added to the ISA? https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/LOCK.html is from a modern manual.  It can emulate any RMW operation, including `std::atomic<double>` addition; C++20 even added a `fetch_add()` member function for FP templates, not just integer.  See [Atomic double floating point or SSE/AVX vector load/store on x86\_64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45055402) and https://preshing.com/20150402/you-can-do-any-kind-of-atomic-read-modify-write-operation

Comment: (It still makes sense that there are no wrapper functions for FP atomic RMWs, since that's not something x86 can do in a single instruction.)

Answer (score 49):

Others have addressed the "why?". It is easy however to roll your own `Add(ref double, double)`, using the `CompareExchange` primitive:

```
public static double Add(ref double location1, double value)
{
    double newCurrentValue = location1; // non-volatile read, so may be stale
    while (true)
    {
        double currentValue = newCurrentValue;
        double newValue = currentValue + value;
        newCurrentValue = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref location1, newValue, currentValue);
        if (newCurrentValue.Equals(currentValue)) // see "Update" below
            return newValue;
    }
}
```

`CompareExchange` sets the value of `location1` to be `newValue`, if the current value equals `currentValue`. As it does so in an atomic, thread-safe way, we can rely on it alone without resorting to locks.

Why the `while (true)` loop? Loops like this are standard when implementing optimistically concurrent algorithms. `CompareExchange` will not change `location1` if the current value is different from `currentValue`. I initialized `currentValue` to `location1` - doing a non-volatile read (which might be stale, but that does not change the correctness, as `CompareExchange` will check the value). If the current value (still) is what we had read from `location1`, `CompareExchange` will change the value to `newValue`. If not, we have to retry `CompareExchange` with the new current value, as returned by `CompareExchange`.

If the value is changed by another thread until the time of our next `CompareExchange` again, it will fail again, necessitating another retry - and this can in theory go on forever, hence the loop. Unless you are constantly changing the value from multiple threads, `CompareExchange` will most likely be called only once, if the current value is still what the non-volatile read of `location1` yielded, or twice, if it was different.

---

**Update** 2022/8/17

As Dr. Strangelove and Theodor Zoulias pointed out in the comments, when `location1 == Double.NaN`, [`Add()` would turn into an infinite loop](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PmB6pM).

So I had to change

```
if (newCurrentValue == currentValue)
```

to

```
if (newCurrentValue.Equals(currentValue))
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more how this works? Why do you loop? And what's the role of CompareExchange?

Comment: This is now an excellent answer! At least now I think I know what optimistic concurrency means: 'Writing concurrent code with the assumption that things will eventually go right.' In case of our while(true) this means we will not loop forever (we're being reasonably optimistic). Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Mzn *pessimistic concurrency*: let's take a lock around multiple operations, because it could go wrong with multiple steps. Reliable, and a reliable bottleneck for concurrent code. *optimistic concurrency*: let's give it a lockless try using `CompareExchange`, because most of the time it will just work with multiple threads, andf if not, we'll just retry. This allows for more concurrency, and is almost always faster. It's not easy to program, and some things just can't be done without locks.

Comment: Could you explain why you set newCurrentValue = 0 rather than setting newCurrentValue = location1? Wouldn't the latter avoid the first loop iteration if the value is != 0? Thanks

Comment: @JamPickle `newCurrentValue = location1` is not thread-safe, as it does not insert a memory barrier. Since .Net 4.5 you could do [`newCurrentValue = Volatile.Read(ref location1)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712899.aspx), but the read memory barrier incurs a performance penalty, so for the case where the current value is `0`, you will have one memory barrier for the volatile read and one for `CompareExchange`. A volatile read however should be - not sure about .Net though - faster than `CompareExchange`, so for current values other than `0` using a volatile read would be faster.

Comment: @JamPickle ctd So it is a tradeoff, although the initial volatile read will probably make it, if only slightly, faster for almost all cases. The signature of the method that I use in practice however, for cases where I know the current value with high probability from a previous write is this: `double Add(ref double location1, double value, double currentValue = 0)`.

Comment: @JamPickle Thinking about the non-volatile assignment "is not thread-safe" again - it does not really matter here, as in those cases where we do read a wrong or stale value (e.g. from the L1 cache), the worst case is that the while loop gets iterated one more time. So maybe what you suggest is in fact a good optimization that will work most of the time - certainly more often than the constant `0` assignment - without the use of a memory barrier. Will mull over it some more and probably adapt my answer accordingly. For the time being, I'll keep the comments, as they reflect the train of thought

Comment: I was thinking along similar lines to your last comment, in that even if it were a stale value, it is more likely to be correct than 0 and could save an iteration. Let me know what you think too. Thanks

Comment: @JamPickle Absolutely! Updated my answer.

Comment: I guess this has a corner case where you end-up in an infinite loop: how best do you address the case where `location1` is `NaN`?

Comment: @Dr.Strangelove I guess that you could use the [`Equals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.equals) method instead of the `==`: `if (newCurrentValue.Equals(currentValue))`. -- *"If two `Double.NaN` values are tested for equality by calling the `Equals` method, the method returns `true`."*

Comment: Note that theoretically a non-volatile read of a `double` value can be [torn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008454/simulate-tearing-a-double-in-c-sharp). Also the `Double.NaN` value has multiple valid binary representations. So it's theoretically possible for a torn `double` value to be equal to `Double.NaN`. I can't think of a problematic scenario, but if you want to be on the safe side prefer `newCurrentValue = Volatile.Read(ref location1)`.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias If you are talking about the first assignment to `newCurrentValue`, before entering the loop: Worst case here is that the loop would need to run one iteration more than strictly necessary - but costing an additional volatile read on every single call. If you are talking about the assignment inside the loop: The [`Interlocked` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked?view=net-6.0) state the class `provides atomic operations for variables that are shared by multiple threads.` So there's no need for `Volatile.Read` there either.

Comment: @EvgeniyBerezovsky I am talking about the first assignment, before entering the loop. I am not 100% sure about the worst case scenario. The problem is that it's possible to create equal `double` values with different underlying `byte[]` data. There is not a one-to-one relationship between bytes and value. This is `true`: `BitConverter.ToDouble(new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0xF8, 0xFF }, 0).Equals(BitConverter.ToDouble(new byte[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0xF8, 0xFF }, 0))`.

Comment: @Dr.Strangelove (Thanks for elaborating, Theodor). I just tested Dr. Strangelove's assertion, and he's right: `double d1 = Double.NaN; Add(ref d1, 2);` spins forever. As Theodor suggested, using `Equals()` instead of `==` fixes the problem. So it looks like `CompareExchange` does not just copy newValue to location1 and return it as is, but `newValue` and `newCurrentValue` will end up being `!=`, but `Equals()`. I have changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: @EvgeniyBerezovsky: In IEEE FP semantics, `NaN == NaN` is always false, even if they have identical bit-patterns.  If your function can only return by an `==` comparison on `double`s producing `true`, that's always a problem.  Nothing to do with `CompareExchange` changing bit-patterns, just the fact that `Interlocked.CompareExchange` doesn't return a separate `bool` so you have to synthesize that from the one output it does produce.  (Unlike C++11 `compare_exchange_weak`/`strong` which update the "expected" arg by reference on CAS failure, and return a `bool` status.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks - I finally understand what's going on here!

Comment: Thank you all for elaborating on this and suggesting a fix.

Comment: @EvgeniyBerezovsky here is the worst case scenario. Imagine that some smart devs have decided to use the `Double.NaN` representation redundancy to store extra bits of information inside it. There are 50 exploitable redundant bits in a `Double.NaN`, so it's not unreasonable. A non-volatile torn read of the `location1` may result in corrupted data stored in the `location1`, after the completion of the `Add`. Corrupted for the purposes of the smart devs of course, who don't regard all `Double.NaN` representations as equal.

Comment: @EvgeniyBerezovsky apart from doing an initial `Volatile.Read` of the `location1` (which is atomic, no risk of reading a torn value), this problem might also be solvable by comparing the bits of the two `double` values, instead of relying on the native APIs provided by the `Double` struct (`==` and `Equals`). For example: `BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(newCurrentValue) == BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(currentValue)`.

Answer (score 7):

As Reed Copsey has said, the Interlocked operations map (via Windows API functions) to instructions supported directly by the x86/x64 processors. Given that one of those functions is XCHG, you can do an atomic XCHG operation without really caring what the bits at the target location represent. In other words, the code can "pretend" that the 64-bit floating point number you are exchanging is in fact a 64-bit integer, and the XCHG instruction won't know the difference. Thus, .Net can provide Interlocked.Exchange functions for floats and doubles by "pretending" that they are integers and long integers, respectively.

However, all of the other operations actually do operate on the individual bits of the destination, and so they won't work unless the values actually represent integers (or bit arrays in some cases.)

Comment: A `lock cmpxchg` retry loop can synthesize any atomic RMW operation you want, as long as you can do a wide enough CAS.  It makes sense that there isn't an Interlocked wrapper function for FP add, but that doesn't stop you from implementing the operation yourself.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap#Example_application:_atomic_adder / https://preshing.com/20150402/you-can-do-any-kind-of-atomic-read-modify-write-operation . See [Atomic double floating point or SSE/AVX vector load/store on x86\_64](//stackoverflow.com/q/45055402) for compiler-generated asm from C++11 `atomic<double>`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that there are two reasons.

1. The processors targeted by .NET support interlocked increment only for integer types.  I believe this is the LOCK prefix on x86, probably similar instructions exist for other processors.
2. Adding one to a floating point number can result in the same number if it is big enough, so I'm not sure if you can call that an increment.  Perhaps the framework designers are trying to avoid nonintuitive behavior in this case.

Comment: Regarding your second point: yes, but I am asking about Interlocked.Add, not Interlocked.Increment.