# Interlock.Add() for double

Tags: c#, double, lock-free

.Net framework has [`Interlocked.Add()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.add.aspx) methods only for `int` and `long`. But I need `Interlock.Add()` for `double` type. How can I do that?

Comment: There's none. read discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400465/why-is-there-no-overload-of-interlocked-add-that-accepts-doubles-as-parameters

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible, which you can read in this question on stackoverflow. It also provides an article about it:

[Why is there no overload of Interlocked.Add that accepts Doubles as parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400465/why-is-there-no-overload-of-interlocked-add-that-accepts-doubles-as-parameters)

Comment: If a question is a duplicate, please post the link as a comment (or, once you have the reputation, vote) rather than in an answer. (Or at least take the effort to write the answer out in your own words :p)