# C++\Cli Interlocked::Add double - how to implement - ref to earlier post

Tags: .net, multithreading, c++-cli, atomic

My question is 99% answered in the post referenced below, but I'd like to know how the method is to be called. Since I cannot comment on the solution provided (too low reputation), I was advised to post my comment as a new question.

Original post and answer (by Eugene): [Why is there no overload of Interlocked.Add that accepts Doubles as parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400465/why-is-there-no-overload-of-interlocked-add-that-accepts-doubles-as-parameters)

Question: trying to program `Parallel::For` loop which requires an Interlocked::Add on doubles, so the example is great. But how do I call this function?

Say B is to be added to A, both are doubles.

Would the call be A = Add(A, B); ? If not, what should it be?

Answer (score -1):

It'd suggest using the "classic" form of lock-free operation:

- Copy the shared variable to a local variable
- Calculate the operation result
- InterlockedCompareExchange the result, local variable and shared variable. If it fails (meaning the shared variable has changed in the meantime), retry the whole operation.

Comment: There is a C# example here that does that: [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd0811yf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which I translated to Cli (doesn't work yet). But it would be nice to know how to call and implement the method provided by Eugene.