# Concurrent modification of double[][] elements without locking

Tags: c#, arrays, multithreading, concurrency, interlocked

I have a jagged `double[][]` array that may be modified concurrently by multiple threads. I should like to make it thread-safe, but if possible, without locks. The threads may well target the same element in the array, that is why the whole problem arises. I have found code to increment double values atomically using the `Interlocked.CompareExchange` method: [Why is there no overload of Interlocked.Add that accepts Doubles as parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400465/why-is-there-no-overload-of-interlocked-add-that-accepts-doubles-as-parameters)

My question is: will it stay atomic if there is a jagged array reference in `Interlocked.CompareExchange`? Your insights are much appreciated.

With an example:

```
    public class Example
    {
        double[][] items;

        public void AddToItem(int i, int j, double addendum)
        {
            double newCurrentValue = items[i][j];
            double currentValue;
            double newValue;
            SpinWait spin = new SpinWait();

            while (true) {
               currentValue = newCurrentValue;
               newValue = currentValue + addendum;
               // This is the step of which I am uncertain:
               newCurrentValue = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref items[i][j], newValue, currentValue);
               if (newCurrentValue == currentValue) break;
               spin.SpinOnce();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Personally, I'd rename `newCurrentValue` to `oldValue` - that's just confusing :)

Comment: Do you realize that while() is basically the same as using a SpinLock but with added complexity?

Comment: @Gusman you do need the loop though - you need to redo from start in the (rare) case of a collision

Comment: @MarcGravell With his code, yes, but the point of the question is to avoid locks, and that loop at the end is the same as a spinlock, so, is not better to use the provided mechanisms than rolling your own?

Comment: @Gusman the only loop in the code that I can see is the "repeat until we succeed" loop that is required and unrelated to spinning; am I missing something?

Comment: After each cycle of the loop the user calls spi.SpinOnce(), and that's exactly what a spinlock will do internally to acquire a lock, so all that code can be resumed using an spinlock to `lock.Enter(ref locked); items[i][j] += addendum; lock.Exit();`

Comment: @Gusman I did not realise but I shall look `SpinLock` up, thank you. Please bear with me, I am a mere physicist :)

Comment: @tethered.sun Np, just was pointing it because if you don't know SpinLocks is not obvious.

Comment: I did some research on the performance of different solutions addressing concurrency, and found this:

http://kejser.org/synchronisation-in-net-part-3-spinlocks-and-interlocks/

I was surprised how competitive an ordinary lock seems in the domain of high contention.

In my task I expect low contention (Monte Carlo simulation of the propagation of photons within a tissue; events that would modify the array are rare, and even then the chance that two such events are concurrent *and* address the very same pixel is very low). In this range, Interlocked operations seem to outperform SpinLock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it will still be atomic and thread-safe. Any calls to the same cell will be passing the same address-to-a-double. Details like whether it is in an array of as a field on an object are irrelevant.

However, the line:

```
double newCurrentValue = items[i][j];
```

is not atomic - that could *in theory* give a torn value (especially on x86). That's actually OK in this case because in the torn-value scenario it will just hit the loop, count as a collision, and redo - this time using the known-atomic value from `CompareExchange`.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that you want eventually add some value to an array item.
I suppose there are only updates of values (array itself stays the same piece of memory) and all updates are done via this `AddToItem` method.
So, you have to read updated value each time (otherwise you lost changes done by other thread, or get infinite loop).

```
public class Example
{
    double[][] items;

    public void AddToItem(int i, int j, double addendum)
    {
        var spin = new SpinWait();

        while (true)
        {
            var valueAtStart = Volatile.Read(ref items[i][j]);
            var newValue = valueAtStart + addendum;

            var oldValue = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref items[i][j], newValue, valueAtStart);

            if (oldValue.Equals(valueAtStart))
                break;
            spin.SpinOnce();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that we have to use some volatile method to read `items[i][j]`. `Volatile.Read` is used to avoid some unwanted optimizations that are allowed under .NET Memory Model (see ECMA-334 and ECMA-335 specifications).
Since we update value atomically (via `Interlocked.CompareExchange`) it's enough to read `items[i][j]` via `Volatile.Read`.
If not all changes to this array are done in this method, then it's better to write a loop in which create local copy of array, modify it and update reference to new array (using `Volatile.Read` and `Interlocked.CompareExchange`)

Comment: And there is not much sense in SpinLock here. In most cases loop itself is more than enough.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions!